# Cheapest motherboard and RAM for AMD Ryzen 3-gen CPU?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining

I brought two Ryzen 9 3900X for mining Monera and I don't have much budget for the Motherboard so I'm looking for cheapest but compatible motherboard for Ryzen 9 3900X? I have same query's as above for the RAM also. So please help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a multitude of places to acquire a motherboard. Any AM4 motherboard is "compatible" so search the internet for AM4 socket motherboards and purchase one within your budget.